# How do I create a new Eloquent model with an incrementing field if the name exists?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Hello i have a schedule table in my database, users are allowed to save their schedules into the database, my problem is a situation where for some reason the user has **Two** schedules with the same name on the **same date**.  I use the **fullCalendar plugin** to capture my info from the user.  Also records are deleted by **title**, **start**, and **end** dates.

I wanted to know if it was possible in eloquent to let the system check for the existence of a particular record and add a number to the title whensaving the record if not found then it would just save the title without the number.

Is this possible? Is there already a feature like this in eloquent? If yes how can it be done.

**Note:** I know i can do this in my controller by checking for existence and adding a number to the retrieved title my question is if there is already a way to do this directly from the model without having to write code in the controller like how **slugs** are generated.

Comment: did you try firstOrCreate

Comment: firstOrCreate will automatically create a new entry in the database if there is no match found. Otherwise it will give you the matched item, i want to add an incrementing number to the record if it exists..

Comment: i think you have to get  record to increment that record

Comment: how about using laravel Accessors & Mutators. [laravel Accessors & Mutators](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)

Answer (score 0):

Well since i was unable to find a solution i just wrote this function instead:

```
/**
 * @param $str
 * @param Model $model
 * @param $column
 * @return string
 */
protected function increment_if_exists($str, \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model $model, $column)
{
    // Finding max ID of any occurrence of specified string
    $max = $model::select($column)->whereRaw($column ." REGEXP '" . addSlashes($str) . "'")
                                        ->orWhereRaw($column ." REGEXP '" . addSlashes($str) . " \\\\([0-9]+\\\\)'")
                                            ->max('id');

    // If 0 matches found supplied string is used.
    // If 1 or more matches found 1 is added to the returned value and appended to supplied string in parenthesis.
    $new =  empty($max) ? $str : $str . ' (' . ($max + 1) . ')';
    return $new;
}
```

I use it in my controller so it's not really exactly what i wanted but perhaps somebody will see this and come up with a way of integrating this into a model so that it does it for you automatically on save.